# How to change the angle of a vector in Pygame?

Tags: python, animation, vector, pygame, rotation

I am currently attempting to code the Craig Reynolds Boids simulation.
However, for the boids to maintain their behavior while avoiding obstacles, I need to be able to steer the boid away from the obstacle by a given angle.
Is there any way of changing the angle of a 2D Vector by a certain angle *theta*?
There might be a quick way using pygame built-in functionality, but I cannot be sure since the website is currently down. However, any way that works (no matter time or space complexity) would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You can view an archived version of the website [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220223214213id_/http://www.pygame.org/docs/).

Comment: What exactly do you mean you have a 2D vector — what is its format? Is it a [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211006193710id_/http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211006193710id_/http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) can be rotated with [`pygame.math.Vector2.rotate`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211006193710id_/http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate) or [`pygame.math.Vector2.rotate_ip`](https://web.archive.org/web/20211006193710id_/http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.rotate_ip):

```py
vec = pygame.math.Vector2(vx, vy)
rotated_vec = vec.rotate(degrees)
```